# Sendto function return error - UDP socket on windows

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2, sendto

I have problem with sendto function. I want to get time from UDP server. My code like this:

```
unsigned char msg[48]={010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char* hostname=(char *)"tick.usno.navy.mil";
sockaddr_in server_addr;
WSAData data;
int result=WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &data );
if (result != NO_ERROR) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", result);
    return 1;
}
int client_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
if (client_s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
unsigned short Port = 123;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 // Address family to use
server_addr.sin_port = htons(Port);           // Port num to use
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname); // IP address to use
char out_buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
int retcode = sendto(client_s, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(msg), sizeof(msg), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
perror("sendto:");
if (retcode == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(client_s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

My output is like:

```
sendto:: No error
sendto failed with error: 10013
```

When I try recive data with recv, I got something wrong. I want get time from UDP server on windows with c++. Where is problem here? Why one error say no error and one error 10013 and how can I fix that?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do know that the value `010` is not *decimal* ten? It's octal and have the decimal value `8`.

Comment: You should check the result of `inet_addr` and you should read [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx). (Hint: that is not a function for resolving host names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old answer (kept below) is informational but not correct for this case.

The problem is most likely these two lines

```
char* hostname=(char *)"tick.usno.navy.mil";
...
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname); // IP address to use
```

The [`inet_addr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function expects a dotted-decimal IPv4 address. Not an unresolved host-name. If not a valid IPv4 dotted-decimal address is provided, the function will return `INADDR_NONE` which is not a valid address and will lead to problems when using the address in e.g. `sendto`. Will it cause the error reported in the question? I honestly don't know, but it will definitely not work as expected.

To resolve a host-name into an IP address you should use [`getaddrinfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The linked reference also contains an example on how to use it.

---

The error `10013` is, if you look at e.g. [this Windows socket error reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WSAEACCESS`, that there is some permission problems. If you then search a little you will see that ports under `1024` are reserved for the system, and you need elevated privileges to use them.

If you want to create an NTP server or client you need to run your program using elevated access rights, like e.g. using "Run as administrator".

---

As for the message

```
sendto:: No error
```

it comes from the `perror` call you unconditionally call after `sendto`. First of all on Windows the socket functions doesn't set `errno` which `perror` uses. Secondly, the state of `errno` is undefined if the previous call to didn't actually fail.

So don't use it unconditionally, and don't use it for the Windows socket functions.

Comment: You should still be able to send to port 123, though.

Comment: If i run as administrator is the same. For perror you have right. Didn't read errno is for only Linux.

Comment: @neiiic Updated my answer

Comment: Yeah you have right. I found for this server IP and know is not problem. With `getaddrinfo` I think I fix this problem too. @JoachimPileborg